# Complex Galois Representaions

Tags: modular-forms, automorphic-forms, galois-representations, l-functions, hecke-characters

I'm trying to understand 1 and 2 dimensional complex representations, induced representations and associated Artin L-functions for a project. I'm finding it hard to find appropriate material to help me get into this on the internet. Can anyone recommend anything?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend N. Snyder's Master's thesis [Artin’s L-functions:
A Historical Approach](http://math.columbia.edu/~nsnyder/thesismain.pdf).